# Display custom field metadata encoded multidimentional array value in WordPress

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress, metadata

Trying to display a Wordpress custom field meta_key value.

The **data** is saved as a WordPress custom field meta_key value

```
$data = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'data', false);
print_r($data); 



Array (
[0] => [
{
"title":"Title A",
"date":"2024-06-06",
"venue":"Venue X"
},
{
"title":"Title B",
"date":"2010-08-08",
"venue":"Venue Y"
}
]
)
```

The **code** I am using

```
<?php
$data = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'data', false);
$size = count($data[0]);
$i = 0;
for( $j = 0; $j < $size; $j++ ) 
{ 
?>
<p>Title: <?php echo $data[$i][$j]['title']; ?></p>
<p>Date: <?php echo $data[$i][$j]['date']; ?></p>
<p>Venue: <?php echo $data[$i][$j]['venue']; ?></p>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

The **output** I am getting

Title: [

Date: [

Venue: [

Any pointers on where its going wrong.

Comment: Your array values appear to be _string_ values, that contain JSON. So you will need to decode the JSON first.

Comment: When I do 
`var_dump(json_decode($data));`
I get NULL

Comment: $data does not contain JSON, the individual elements _in_ $data do. So you need to loop over them, and decode each one separately.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data displayed, you need to:

- Set the 3rd argument from `get_post_meta()` function to `true` instead of `false`,
- Use `json_decode()` function on it (as it's JSON encoded),
- Use a `foreach` loop, instead of a `for` loop.

Try the following:

```php
$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'data', true);
$data = json_decode($meta);

foreach ( $data as $object ) { 
    if ( isset($object->title) ) {
        printf('<p>%s: %s</p>', __('Title'), $object->title );
    }
    if ( isset($object->date) ) {
        printf('<p>%s: %s</p>', __('Date'),  $object->date );
    }
    if ( isset($object->venue) ) {
        printf('<p>%s: %s</p>', __('Venue'), $object->venue );
    }
}
```

It should work.